# Module not found: Can't resolve 'file-saver' in '/home/node/app/src/reducers'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, xlsx, filesaver.js

i ran the installer and returned:

```
npm install xlsx file-saver

added 10 packages, and audited 15 packages in 13s

1 high severity vulnerability

Some issues need review, and may require choosing a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

the audit:

```
npm audit

# npm audit report

xlsx  *
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in sheetJS - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4r6h-8v6p-xvw6
No fix available
node_modules/xlsx

1 high severity vulnerability

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

the npm update said that is up to date and also added to package.json

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  }
}
```

Why is showing this error?

Comment: please add code where you're importing the node_module `file-saver`

Comment: here is the code in the file: 
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

Comment: ***What*** error are you referring to? If you are referring to the "security vulnerability" message, well that's just a ***warning***. Run `npm audit fix` to see if they can be "patched" on their own, otherwise, they can typically be ignored.

Comment: i get the Module not found: Can't resolve 'file-saver' in '/home/node/app/src/reducers'

Comment: and the npm audit return no fix available